# Crystal XI memory management, C# Managed code

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-xi

How do you handle Crystal reports XI memory management. We have found that in our reporting solution, we run out of memory once we try to produce multi threaded reports?

Is this purely based on the fact that Crystal is not pure managed code?

Crystal Business Objects developer (under cloack) welcome to comment X-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you reviewed the Crystal Reports Memory Issue Trouble Shooting documentation?

[Troubleshooting Tips for various types of memory errors](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/boc/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/40838c3f-6d1e-2b10-baa7-923cb79094a9?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true)

Comment: Will have a look thanx, didnt even know such a document exists. X-)